# Chatbot - Persistent Menu for Bot still works after Handover

Tags: botframework, messenger

I have developed a chatbot using Azure's Bot Framework, and am using the Facebook Messenger channel. I also have a persistent menu that I am using for easy quick actions. And I am also using the Handover Protocol to pass thread control between my Bot and my human customer support.

The problem I am finding is that even after I use the Handover to pass thread control to my human customer support, basically disabling my bot, it will still answer to the user if they use the persistent menu actions. Is there any way for me to disable this, for the persistent menu only being shown or active, or have its actions only functioning when the thread control belongs to the Bot?

Comment: It's possible that the persistent menu still being functional despite the handover could be due to two reasons: persistent menus are designed to be constantly active, and possibly because the handover isn't working the way it should due to it not being supported in the bot framework.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue looking for some recommendations.
Have you got some thing on this which resolved your issue or still this is an issue for your bot ?

Comment: It's still an issue, I'm on vacations right now so I haven't looked at it much further, although I created a support ticket on facebook, and they're researching it I suppose, if and when I know anything more I'll comment here.